# Sum with Column Header

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet where it has  duplicate column header titles labeled "'H ". I'm attempting to calculate the sum of a row if it is under this certain header value. I tried pivot tables but it hasn't worked too well.. I feel as though I'm not using the sumif properly.

Please help this excel beginner!

This is what I used so far:
=SUMIF(B$2:$M5, B$2:$M5="'Q ", B6:M6)

above is what my data would look like, below is the summary that I would want

[image]

Comment: Provide an example of data, and your expected result?

Comment: You're trying to retain the header and sum up what is in row 2 if the row 6 value is "Q"?  `="Header "&Sumif($B$2:$M$2,"Q ",$B$6:$M$6)`.  I am unsure what is going on with your data, the condition applies per count in the array, e.g., range is B2:M2 so 1 = B2, 2 = C2, and in the sum range of B6:M6 1 = B6, 2 = C6, etc.

Comment: @cyril I was trying to retain the header and sum row 6, if the value in row 2 is "Q"

Comment: @chucklukowski done

Comment: @erty234 Sorry, I was thinking of `SumIfs` where the sum range is the first argument.  `Sumif($B$2:$M$2,"Q",$B$6:$M$6)` would sum up row 6 if row 2 has "Q" for a value.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your image, and assuming it starts on A1, use this code in Cell B5 and copy it to the right.

```
=SUMIF($B$1:$G$1,B$4,$B$2:$G$2)
```

[image: Example Result]

Answer (score 0):

so the SUMIF function requires three values:

1. the range which you are searching.
2. the criteria (value) you are searching for.
3. the range which you want to return for your sum.

so in your case, I think it might look like this if you are searching column headers to find values in the columns/rows below them:

=SUMIF($A$2:$A$10,$A$1,B2:B10)

This would return the sum of all cells in row B that are under column headers shown in the range A2:A10 with the value shown in A1 (you can change the value in A1 to "H", "Q", or whatever you like).  You could copy this formula down for all of the rest of your rows if you have multiple rows to find values for.

Hopefully this helps.

JW